# To check whether the given number series is in Arithmetic progression or Geometric progression or Harmonic progression

Tags: java

I am writing a program to check whether the given number series is in AP, GP or HP. I know that AP is based on common difference and GP is based on common ratio. My code works for AP and GP but fails for HP. What corrections should be made in the following code, also is there a way to optimize my code. Following is the program:

```
import java.util.*;
class APGPHP 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int n;
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the series");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = s.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
    for (int i = 0;i<n ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number ["+(i+1)+"] :");
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    CheckAPGPHP(a); 
}

public static void CheckAPGPHP(int[] a)
{
    if(a.length<3)
    {
        System.out.println("Array should contain atleast 3 elements ");
        return;
    }
    if(CheckAP(a) == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("AP");
        if (CheckHP(a) == 1)
            System.out.println("HP");
    }

    if(CheckGP(a) == 1)
        System.out.println("GP");
}

public static int CheckAP(int[] a)
{
    int iDiff=a[1]-a[0];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
    {
        if((a[i+1]-a[i])!=iDiff)
            return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}

public static int CheckGP(int[] a)
{
    int iRatio=a[1]/a[0];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
    {
        if((a[i+1]/a[i])!=iRatio)
            return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}

public static int CheckHP(int[] a)
{
    float[] b = new float[a.length];
    for (int i =0;i<=b.length-1 ;i++ )
    {
        b[i] = 1.0f/a[i];
    }
    float iDiff=b[1]-b[0];
    for(int i=0;i<b.length-1;i++)
    {
        if((b[i+1]-b[i])!=iDiff)
            return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of checking equality, check if the numbers are within some small tolerance of each other, such as 1e-6 or so. The reason is that float division is not exact.

For example, in python (5.0 - 4.9) returns 0.09999999999999964, instead of .1. I know this is not division, but it's a simple example to show that floating point arithmetic is not exact.

Comment: You mean i should specify the number of digits of precision in case of float like
`b[i] = (float,2) 1.0f/a[i];`
??

Comment: I mean instead of checking if x!=ratio, check if abs(x-ratio)<tolerance

Answer (score 1):

I see **three** major issues with your code.  There may be other minor issues.

- You have put your call to `CheckHP` inside the branch that only runs if `CheckAP` returns 1.  So you'll only ever check that the numbers are in harmonic progression if they turn out to be in arithmetic progression.  So it's never going to return true (since the numbers can only be both in arithmetic progression and harmonic progression if they're all equal).
- You're going to have floating point precision problems.  It's safest to check the harmonic progression using only integers, and multiplication instead of division.  Use the fact that `a, b, c` is a harmonic progression if and only if `a * b, a * c, b * c` is an arithmetic progression.  Then check this using only integer arithmetic.
- The integer divisions in your `CheckGP` method are going to give you positive results, when you have numbers that are not in geometric progression.  Integer divisions round down, and you don't want to do that.  The best way to check whether `a, b, c` is a geometric progression is to compare `a * c` to `b * b`.

Incidentally, your various checking functions return `1` or `-1` to mean true or false.  Why not just make their return types `boolean`, and return `true` or `false`?

Also, you need to think about integer overflow.  Think about how large are the numbers you'll be dealing with are.  Would it be safer for you to use `long` or even `BigInteger` in place of `int`?

Comment: You are correct. I removed the call for HP from AP block as you said. Also changed the return types of all the functions to boolean. Now the code works fine. Here is the code :
`public static boolean CheckHP(int[] a)
    {
    int[] b = new int []{a[0]*a[1],a[0]*a[2],a[1]*a[2]};
    if(CheckAP(b))
        return true;

    return false;
}`
Here i have hardcoded the values in array b, so its checking only for the first 3 terms. Should i put it in a for loop and create the b array using all elements in a?
Lastly, is my logic for AP and GP correct?
Thank you. :)

Comment: Your logic for AP is fine.  Your logic for GP is wrong.  I will edit my answer.